# make smaller space between title and link

Tags: css

I'm trying to make smaller space between title and the links, but I can't figure that out: http://prntscr.com/ejx033 - the website is: http://94.247.169.169/~welloteket/ can anyone help me out? I can't find the CSS code.

I've been trying to edit size of the padding

```
padding: 0px;
```

but no, it doesn't works either.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to `ubermenu-target` attribute: `padding-bottom: 0;`

```
.ubermenu-skin-grey-white .ubermenu-submenu .ubermenu-item-header.ubermenu-has-submenu-stack > .ubermenu-target {
   border-bottom: none;
   padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Much better. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
.ubermenu .ubermenu-submenu-type-stack {
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.ubermenu-submenu-type-stack {
padding-top: 0;
}
```

If it will be insufficient then you can also decrease padding of `.ubermenu-target` padding because now you have:

```
.ubermenu-target {
padding: 15px 20px;
}
```